# Есть ли утилита для автоисправления delete в C++?

Tags: c++, сборщик-мусора, memory

Есть много сгенерированного кода c++ без использования оператора delete. Нужна утилита для автоматического исправления этого, которая бы записывала delete в нужные места.
Не надо советовать всякие "умные указатели" и "сборщики мусора" и говорить типа: "Утилита для исправления программы = программист".

Comment: На 99% уверен, что такой утилиты нет - это что-то из области фантастики. 
Даже если и есть что-то подобное, то наверняка результаты ее работы потребуется десять раз проверить. Так что как бы вам это ни было костью в горле, однако действительно - "утилита для исправления программы = программист"

Comment: А нет возможности управлять сгенерированным кодом? Например, заменить синтаксически неудобный `new` на `malloc`? Покажите фрагмент сгенерированногго кода.

Comment: @VladD, код конвертируется этой утилитой https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/j2c/

Comment: @Yaskhan  Ashimbaev, но ведь Ваша куча кода не на Java (утилита -- конвертор Java 1.6 в С++11), а на С++.

100% она начнет ругаться на крестовые сорсы.

--

Раз код, как Вы говорите, *сгенерирован*, так может лучше поискать более адекватный генератор?  
(imho лучше всего переписать все с нуля, *но только умелыми руками*).

Comment: @avp: Судя по всему, у ТС есть код на Java, который нужно сконвертировать в C++. Понятно, что освобождение памяти автоконвертеру взять неоткуда.

@Yaskhan  Ashimbaev: Но всё же, покажите сконвертированный код. Если задача у вас стоит во всей общности — сконвертировать в правильный C++ _любой_ код на Java, — то я бы не тратил время и сконвертировал руками. Заоlно получится гораздо более идиоматический C++.

Comment: @Yaskhan  Ashimbaev, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

В общем случае подобная утилита невозможна.

Преимущество (одновременно и недостаток) языков с ручным управлением памятью в том-то и состоит, что выделенная вручную память освобождается не в момент, который может быть вычислен заранее, а при помощи логики программиста. При этом такой подход при вдумчивом и аккуратном программировании может быть эффективнее различных автоматических или полуавтоматических систем управления памятью.

Если бы можно было автоматически вычислить тот самый момент, когда память можно освобождать, не было бы нужды в `delete`: компилятор мог бы *сам* вставить `delete` в нужном месте.

Язык C++ пошёл фактически по пути отказа от ручного управления памятью: идиоматическим считается полуавтоматическое освобождение памяти при помощи подсчёта ссылок. (Да-да, тот самый `shared_ptr`.) Вы можете попробовать таки настроить ваш генератор вручную, чтобы он выдавал `shared_ptr` вместо нативных указателей. Но того самого «правильного» места освобождения памяти автоматически никто за вас не найдёт.

Поэтому те альтернативы, которые вы перечислили (умные указатели и «программист») — по существу единственные доступные. Сожалею об этом.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, может, вам [эта статья](http://www.gamedev.ru/code/tip/?id=3881) поможет. Сразу только не бейте, сам таким способом не пользовался.